# STR_TO_DATE outputs NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the use of the STR_TO_DATE function.

My date has the following format

```
24.04.2012 11:24:50:360
```

I want to write it in my MySQL Column, where the format is

```
2012-04-24 11:24:50
```

To check if my statement is correct, I'm testing it with

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('24.04.2012 11:24:50:360', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Everytime I run this, it returns NULL. I have no idea how I have to correct the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('24.04.2012 11:24:50:360', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

(the format in your statement is not correct, you need to swap the year month and day, and you need to use . as a separator)

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! I vote up und check as soon as it is available